# Manually insert data into Lists

Tags: c#, list, input, output, user-input

I have this little Hospital program that I'm doing.

I already have a list of Users in it.

```
class Program
{
        public static List<Medico> ListaMedico = new List<Medico>();
        public static List<Tecnico_Atendimento> ListaTecnicosAtendimento = new List<Tecnico_Atendimento>();
        public static List<Utente> ListaUtente = new List<Utente>();
        public static List<Urgencia> ListaUrgencia = new List<Urgencia>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Lista de Medicos

            ListaMedico.Add(new Medico(52, "Antonio", 555444333, "antonio@gmail.com", "Dermatologista"));
            ListaMedico.Add(new Medico(34, "Lucas", 555444333, "lucas78@gmail.com", "Cardiologista"));
            ListaMedico.Add(new Medico(35, "Duarte", 555444333, "Duarte90@gmail.com", "Otorrino"));
            ListaMedico.Add(new Medico(32, "Marcos", 555444333, "marcos123@gmail.com", "Clinica Geral"));
            ListaMedico.Add(new Medico(45, "Pedro", 555444333, "Pedro12@gmail.com", "Pediatra"));
            ListaMedico.Add(new Medico(25, "Pedro", 555444333, "Pedro12@gmail.com", "Urologia"));

            //listaTecnicosAtendimento

            ListaTecnicosAtendimento.Add(new Tecnico_Atendimento(22, "Daniel", 555444333, "dany@gmail.com"));
            ListaTecnicosAtendimento.Add(new Tecnico_Atendimento(33, "Eduardo", 111222333, "edu@gmail.com"));
            ListaTecnicosAtendimento.Add(new Tecnico_Atendimento(22, "Rui", 333111222, "rui@gmail.com"));

            // - ListaUtentes (presentes no Centro de Saúde)

            ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(123457, "Pedro", 914754123, "pedro@gmail.com"));
            ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(147854, "Lucas", 974123214, "lucas91@gmail.com"));
            ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(147516, "Rodrigo", 941201456, "rodrigo00@gmail.com"));
            ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(196473, "Gaspar", 987453210, "gaspar@gmail.com"));
            ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(154778, "Assis", 974120219, "assis@gmail.com"));


            // - ListaUrgências

            DateTime data = new DateTime(2017, 12, 12);
            ListaUrgencia.Add(new Urgencia(001, data, "Gripe", 225544887, 22));
            ListaUrgencia.Add(new Urgencia(002, data, "Hepatite", 225544887, 22));
            ListaUrgencia.Add(new Urgencia(003, data, "HIV", 225544887, 22));
            ListaUrgencia.Add(new Urgencia(004, data, "Cancro", 225544887, 22));
            ListaUrgencia.Add(new Urgencia(005, data, "Constipacao", 225544887, 22));

            Menu();
    }
```

And I have a menu option that Displays all this data. Ex: Press 1 to show Medics and it lists and the medics in `"ListaMedico"`.

```
static void ConsultarListaMedicos()
{
     {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
            Console.WriteLine("        =============================================================== ");
            Console.WriteLine("        ===================== Lista de Medicos ======================== ");
            Console.WriteLine("        ===============================================================\n\n ");
            ListaMedico.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        }
    }
```

Now I need to add an option for the user to input through the keyboard his own Medics.

What should I add to my code to allow this?

Comment: What is `Menu()`? Console? Or?

Comment: Why don't you just ask the user to type the properties you need through `Console.ReadLine()`?

Comment: Take each input through `Console.Readline();` , create a new instance of `Medico` and add it to your list. What is the problem?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried just walking user through asking questions and having them enter data, and then once all items for a record corrected, add it to your list(s)?

Comment: I need to have an Option on the menu  like this : Insert your Medic into the List. And it should read the user input and added it to Medics list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Console.ReadLine()` method ([MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx)). You will probably want to obtain each property seperately.

```
int age;
string name;

Console.WriteLine("Enter age:");
age = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Enter name:");
name = Console.ReadLine();

...

ListaMedico.Add(new Medico(age, name, ...)
```

(fill the rest yourself)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the sugestion. Gonna try to do it and will report in.

Comment: I did that but how do I insert the data entered into the previous list I created?

Comment: the input will be stored in the variables. Once you have collected them all, you simply add to the list, the same way as you already do. I modified the example, to indicate how.